# Detect Angular Material Menu DOM Insertion

Tags: angular, angular-material, menu, event-handling, angular-directive

I am in search of a method that executes after a Mat Menu has been opened and inserted into the DOM. My goal is to check the height of the menu once it is fully drawn.

I have attempted the following code:

```
<img src="assets/img/info.svg"
     #menuTrigger="matMenuTrigger"
     [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu"
     (menuOpened)="menuOpened()">
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
</mat-menu>
```

However, the menuOpened event fires before the menu is fully drawn, resulting in an incorrect height measurement.

Any suggestions on how to ensure that my code runs after the menu has been completely drawn?

I'm using Angular 11

Comment: Have you tried accessing the menu in the ngAfterViewInit hook?

Comment: In the function menuOpened() you could register a callback for afterNextRender https://angular.io/api/core/afterNextRender

Comment: @ThomasRenger I forgot to mention that I'm using Angular 11, and this feature is not available in this version. Thank you.

Comment: @MishaMashina how can it help me?  The ngAfterViewInit doesn't emit when the mat menu is opened.

Comment: @LoveAllThingsCode I thought in your scenario you just wanted to get the position/size of the menu even when not open, but I guess I misunderstood. Anyway, the docs (https://v7.material.angular.io/components/menu/overview#toggling-the-menu-programmatically) show that you can get a ViewChild reference for the menu and trigger it programatically, so you can attach a method to some button (icon, whatever, as you did with `MatMenuTrigger`) and have a ts method to open the menu, then maybe do a setTimeout in the same method, to capture the position/size once it's open.

Comment: @MishaMashina Yes, I want to know the size of the menu after it opens, as its height depends on the content. Can you please explain more on your suggestion?

Comment: enclosed all inside a `setTimeout(()=>{...here..})` This makes that you execute the function inside when Angular have drawed the menu